# Android drawable sizes for different screens

Tags: android, image, scale, drawable, dpi

I've read a lot of different posts and articles about how screen sizes are determined and it's pretty confusing to say the least so I thought I'd just ask!

Here are the facts:

- I have developed an app that has a big logo on the login screen. This logo is 958x496 and is 30.6KB. It's a real nice big sharp looking image!
- I have four development phones that each use different drawable sizes ranging from hdpi to xxxhdpi.
- I currently have a dawable-nodpi folder that has the logo in and every phone uses it but I feel like this isn't the 'proper' way to do it so I'm trying to have different sized images for each phone.

So, I want to use this full 958x496 image as the baseline for the xxxhdpi drawable and I will scale them down accordingly using the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio (meaning the full image will be my '16').

As it currently stands if I do that, for the hdpi phone I get an image that is 354x183 as its roughly 37% of full size. I run up the app and yes the logo looks great but **here is the question..** if I use drawable-nodpi instead it will use the full 958x496 image and it looks better so why should I downsize my image when it will look slightly blurry? Why not just use the best possible version of the image? I thought this was because I wouldn't get the benefits of the high quality image on the lesser phone, but you can definitely tell a difference.

Comment: The base is always the mdpi (160 dpi) density. hdpi is 1.5 times the mdpi density, xhdpi is 2 times, xxhdpi is 3 times and xxxhdpi is 4 times. So, if the image is 958x496 at xxxhdpi, it would be approx 240x124 at mdpi. Do the appropriate multiplications to get the hdpi (* 1.5), xhdpi (* 2) and xxhdpi (* 3) sizes.

Comment: I know and I have. But it looks better when I have the full 958x496 image looks better on my hdpi phone. So whats the point in using the scaled down version?

Comment: Well, then you started from the wrong xxxhdpi size. Actually, `960x540` is a standard **hdpi** resolution (along with `800x400` and `800x480`). And 958x496 is tremendously close to `960x540`

Comment: Oh, thats what I have been looking for. Basically how high quality my images are now. Can you refer me to a source that could help with that?

Comment: Something like this? http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php